# Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.Ss0VJv (%build)

Tags: linux, rpmbuild

I am trying to build an rpm file to install ATM drivers. The final step to build the rpm file is to use this rpmbuild command
    [anjanu@matrix rpmbuild]$ rpmbuild -bb SPECS/isaratm.spec

but after excuting the command I get this whole lot of output with some error in the end which I don't understand.

```
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.CwAhLg
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ /bin/rm -rf isaratm
+ /bin/gzip -dc ../SOURCES/isaratm-source.tar.gz
+ tar -xvvf -
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           11901 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/ia.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           10362 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/ia_api.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            6598 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/ia_query.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            3831 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/ia_control.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           20876 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/ia_vc.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            5199 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/ia_oam.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           20869 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/ia_alarm.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            6739 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/ia_alarms.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           11559 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/ia_phy.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           15282 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/ia_util.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            9077 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/ia_rs.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           19475 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/cx28250.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           60109 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/ia_dumps.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            5581 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isar_api.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           17809 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isar_codes.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           10210 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isar_conf.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            4880 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isar_diag.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           25168 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isar_linux.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            6821 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isar_close.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            6980 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isar_probe.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            7120 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isar_prom.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            9610 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isar_pvc.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            5150 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isar_phy.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            5132 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isar_dtin.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            6045 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isar_pav.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            7506 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isar_tune.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            4800 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isar_vc.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            5156 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isar_pckt.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0          203037 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isartest.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           23228 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/apiRecv.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           44616 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/apiRecvM.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           26761 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/apiRecvRaw.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           28823 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/apiSend.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           23183 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/apiSendRaw.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           38854 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isartool.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0          101161 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isaralarm.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           25148 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isarxbr.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           11675 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isarcbr.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           15968 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isarconfig.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           13181 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/rs_dumps.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            5504 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/eeprom.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           11829 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/clipoa.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            6644 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/config.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           11142 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/config.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            8760 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/config_tool.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           11983 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/configs.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            4550 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/ia_dumps.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           10743 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/ia.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            2102 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/ia_alarm.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           32672 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/ia_incs.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            7636 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/ia_rs.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            4123 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/ia_types.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            6750 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/isar_alarms.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           20577 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/isar_api.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            3355 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isar_build.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            9666 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/isar_codes.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            5428 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isar_conf.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            9573 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/isar_diag.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            4857 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/isar_linux.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            5222 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isar_pav.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            7191 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/isar_phy.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            7604 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/isar_types.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            5031 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isarconf.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            5023 2006-08-10 23:40 isaratm/src/isarconfig.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           10427 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/isartool.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            7100 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/isarxbr.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            5388 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/isarcbr.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           12371 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/pvcs.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           37986 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/rs8234.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            3033 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/rs_dumps.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            3308 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/rs_log.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           19619 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/rs_rsm.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            7322 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/rs_sch.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           18130 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/rs_seg.h
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            5980 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/rs_sep.h
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0            6485 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/Makefile.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           18962 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/ia_os_linux.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           89962 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/linux_atm.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           36756 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/linux_api.c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            9280 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/src/ia_linux.h
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/out/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           30189 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/out/libisar.o
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0           43769 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/out/isarconfig
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0           46326 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/out/isarxbr
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0             247 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/out/mknod-isaratm
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           15270 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/out/isarconf.0
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           40132 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/out/isar-core-reg.o
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           40572 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/out/isar-core-stack.o
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0             848 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/Makefile
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0            2855 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/make_api
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0            1179 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/make_drvr.k24
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0            1237 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/make_drvr.k26
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0              76 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/AUTHORS
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0            2578 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/COPYING
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0             695 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/COMPAT
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            2723 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/files.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0           28204 2006-08-10 23:41 isaratm/README
+ exit 0
Executing(%build): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.Ss0VJv
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
++ grep -m 1 VERSION /usr/src/linux/Makefile
++ cut -c 2-
++ cut -d = -f2
grep: /usr/src/linux/Makefile: No such file or directory
+ K_MAJ=
++ grep -m 1 PATCHLEVEL /usr/src/linux/Makefile
++ cut -c 2-
++ cut -d = -f2
grep: /usr/src/linux/Makefile: No such file or directory
+ K_MIN=
++ grep -m 1 SUBLEVEL /usr/src/linux/Makefile
++ cut -d = -f2
++ cut -c 2-
grep: /usr/src/linux/Makefile: No such file or directory
+ K_SUB=
++ grep -m 1 EXTRAVERSION /usr/src/linux/Makefile
++ cut -d = -f2
++ cut -d ' ' -f2
grep: /usr/src/linux/Makefile: No such file or directory
+ K_XTR=
+ K_VER=..
++ grep CONFIG_REGPARM /usr/src/linux/.config
++ cut -c16
grep: /usr/src/linux/.config: No such file or directory
+ K_REG=
++ whoami
+ K_WHO=anjanu
+ cd isaratm
+ cp Makefile src/
+ cp make_drvr.k24 src/
+ cp make_drvr.k26 src/
+ '[' -lt 6 ']'
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.Ss0VJv: line 45: [: -lt: unary operator expected
+ case $K_REG in
+ cp out/isar-core-stack.o src/isar-core.o
+ cd src/
+ make
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-279.el6.i686/build SUBDIRS=/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-279.el6.i686'
  CC [M]  /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.o
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:15,
                 from include/linux/cache.h:4,
                 from include/linux/time.h:7,
                 from include/linux/ktime.h:24,
                 from include/linux/poll.h:9,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_linux.h:91,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:49,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.c:37:
include/linux/bitops.h:6:1: warning: "BIT" redefined
In file included from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:37,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.c:37:
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/isar_types.h:199:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
  CC [M]  /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_api.o
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:15,
                 from include/linux/cache.h:4,
                 from include/linux/time.h:7,
                 from include/linux/ktime.h:24,
                 from include/linux/poll.h:9,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_linux.h:91,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:49,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_api.c:37:
include/linux/bitops.h:6:1: warning: "BIT" redefined
In file included from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:37,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_api.c:37:
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/isar_types.h:199:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
  CC [M]  /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_query.o
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:15,
                 from include/linux/cache.h:4,
                 from include/linux/time.h:7,
                 from include/linux/ktime.h:24,
                 from include/linux/poll.h:9,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_linux.h:91,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:49,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_query.c:29:
include/linux/bitops.h:6:1: warning: "BIT" redefined
In file included from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:37,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_query.c:29:
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/isar_types.h:199:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
  CC [M]  /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_control.o
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:15,
                 from include/linux/cache.h:4,
                 from include/linux/time.h:7,
                 from include/linux/ktime.h:24,
                 from include/linux/poll.h:9,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_linux.h:91,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:49,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_control.c:32:
include/linux/bitops.h:6:1: warning: "BIT" redefined
In file included from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:37,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_control.c:32:
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/isar_types.h:199:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
  CC [M]  /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_vc.o
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:15,
                 from include/linux/cache.h:4,
                 from include/linux/time.h:7,
                 from include/linux/ktime.h:24,
                 from include/linux/poll.h:9,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_linux.h:91,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:49,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_vc.c:37:
include/linux/bitops.h:6:1: warning: "BIT" redefined
In file included from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:37,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_vc.c:37:
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/isar_types.h:199:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
  CC [M]  /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_oam.o
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:15,
                 from include/linux/cache.h:4,
                 from include/linux/time.h:7,
                 from include/linux/ktime.h:24,
                 from include/linux/poll.h:9,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_linux.h:91,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:49,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_oam.c:35:
include/linux/bitops.h:6:1: warning: "BIT" redefined
In file included from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:37,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_oam.c:35:
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/isar_types.h:199:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
  CC [M]  /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_alarm.o
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:15,
                 from include/linux/cache.h:4,
                 from include/linux/time.h:7,
                 from include/linux/ktime.h:24,
                 from include/linux/poll.h:9,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_linux.h:91,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:49,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_alarm.c:31:
include/linux/bitops.h:6:1: warning: "BIT" redefined
In file included from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:37,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_alarm.c:31:
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/isar_types.h:199:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
  CC [M]  /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_alarms.o
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:15,
                 from include/linux/cache.h:4,
                 from include/linux/time.h:7,
                 from include/linux/ktime.h:24,
                 from include/linux/poll.h:9,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_linux.h:91,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:49,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_alarms.c:31:
include/linux/bitops.h:6:1: warning: "BIT" redefined
In file included from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:37,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_alarms.c:31:
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/isar_types.h:199:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_alarms.c: In function 'isa_close':
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_alarms.c:137: warning: 'stat' may be used uninitialized in this function
  CC [M]  /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_phy.o
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:15,
                 from include/linux/cache.h:4,
                 from include/linux/time.h:7,
                 from include/linux/ktime.h:24,
                 from include/linux/poll.h:9,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_linux.h:91,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:49,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_phy.c:31:
include/linux/bitops.h:6:1: warning: "BIT" redefined
In file included from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:37,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_phy.c:31:
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/isar_types.h:199:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
  CC [M]  /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_util.o
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:15,
                 from include/linux/cache.h:4,
                 from include/linux/time.h:7,
                 from include/linux/ktime.h:24,
                 from include/linux/poll.h:9,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_linux.h:91,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:49,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_util.c:34:
include/linux/bitops.h:6:1: warning: "BIT" redefined
In file included from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:37,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_util.c:34:
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/isar_types.h:199:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
  CC [M]  /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_rs.o
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:15,
                 from include/linux/cache.h:4,
                 from include/linux/time.h:7,
                 from include/linux/ktime.h:24,
                 from include/linux/poll.h:9,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_linux.h:91,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:49,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_rs.c:31:
include/linux/bitops.h:6:1: warning: "BIT" redefined
In file included from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:37,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_rs.c:31:
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/isar_types.h:199:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
  CC [M]  /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_os_linux.o
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:15,
                 from include/linux/cache.h:4,
                 from include/linux/time.h:7,
                 from include/linux/ktime.h:24,
                 from include/linux/poll.h:9,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_linux.h:91,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:49,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_os_linux.c:80:
include/linux/bitops.h:6:1: warning: "BIT" redefined
In file included from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:37,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_os_linux.c:80:
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/isar_types.h:199:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_os_linux.c: In function 'DMA_ALLOC':
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia_os_linux.c:635: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
  CC [M]  /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/linux_atm.o
In file included from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/ia.h:37,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/linux_atm.c:133:
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/isar_types.h:199:1: warning: "BIT" redefined
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:15,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-279.el6.i686/arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:45,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-279.el6.i686/arch/x86/include/asm/current.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-279.el6.i686/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:15,
                 from include/linux/prefetch.h:14,
                 from include/linux/list.h:7,
                 from include/linux/module.h:9,
                 from /home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/linux_atm.c:108:
include/linux/bitops.h:6:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/linux_atm.c: In function 'ia_init_module':
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/linux_atm.c:369: error: implicit declaration of function 'pci_module_init'
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/linux_atm.c: At top level:
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/linux_atm.c:401: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/linux_atm.c: In function 'ia_probe':
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/linux_atm.c:604: error: 'SA_INTERRUPT' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/linux_atm.c:604: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/linux_atm.c:604: error: for each function it appears in.)
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/linux_atm.c:604: error: 'SA_SHIRQ' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/linux_atm.c:604: warning: passing argument 2 of 'request_irq' from incompatible pointer type
include/linux/interrupt.h:123: note: expected 'irq_handler_t' but argument is of type 'enum irqreturn_t (*)(int,  void *, struct pt_regs *)'
make[2]: *** [/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/linux_atm.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-279.el6.i686'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.Ss0VJv (%build)


RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.Ss0VJv (%build)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The driver you try to install is a bit old. It uses SA_INTERRUPT and SA_SHIRQ which leads to an error:

```
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/linux_atm.c: In function 'ia_probe':
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/linux_atm.c:604: error: 'SA_INTERRUPT' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/linux_atm.c:604: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/linux_atm.c:604: error: for each function it appears in.)
/home/anjanu/rpmbuild/BUILD/isaratm/src/linux_atm.c:604: error: 'SA_SHIRQ' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I don't know about SA_INTERRUPT but SA_SHIRQ seems to have been removed from the kernel: [Kernel 2.6.22 has told us that it was going to deprecate it although still defines it, but in kernel 2.6.25 this SA_SHIRQ is now gone](http://technostuff.blogspot.de/2008/04/there-is-still-problem-with-beta2.html)

You've got a 2.6.32 kernel so I guess you have to look for a newer driver or port / migrate it to the newer kernel yourself.